# select combination of two columns sql, h2

Tags: sql, combinations, distinct, h2, rdbms

Hello i have this table:

[image]

In this table i want to check, if the combination of the columns: 'carrier' and 'flight' always give the same origin. How can i do that?

I tried this one:

```
select distinct(a.name)
from carriers c, flights f, airports a
where c.id = f.carrier and a.id = f.origin;
```

but i dont think it's giving me what i wanted to know. Really grateful for any advice.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this query returns any rows, then you'll get exactly which combination of `carrier` + `flight` has multiple origins

```
select carrier, flight, count(distinct origin) as number_of_origins
from flights
group by carrier, flight
having count(distinct origin) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query tells you if there are any `carrier` + `flight` combinations related to more than one `origin`:

```
select carrier, flight
from flights
group by carrier, flight
having count(distinct origin) > 1
```